# Javascript onclick getvalue is undefined

Tags: javascript

my problem has 2 sides to it.

I am trying to send a simple get value that is generated via a loop like so:

```
    for(var x=0; x<del.length; x++) {
        del[x].onclick = function () {
        WORK(x);
        }
    }
```

Here is my frustrated WORK function

```
   function WORK (x) {
        var y = ids[x];
        var url = "Delete.php?val=" + y;
        window.location = url;
    }
```

I know i just have to pass the value to the function...but if i set it up like that the page executes the function on load and doesn't wait for my click and as is it is now it will always pass an undefined value...what is going on here?

Comment: What is `del`? Is it a collection of DOM nodes? It would be useful to see some HTML and some of the other code. The big thing is you're always going to have `x` as the last value for all clicks due to scoping issues.

Comment: as pointed out by @Andy you will always get x as last value, you need to use clousre inside a anonymous function, to bind your data correctly on click event , there are lot of article on this topic

Comment: well it's a collection of all the td's with the class name delete, basically i wanted to make delete buttons that send a value with the row id via GET, i know ajax can do this better but this seemed more fun :o.

Comment: Use event delegation instead. Attach an event listener to `<table>` and catch the events from the buttons as they bubble up the DOM. Simpler and you're using listeners sparingly

Comment: @BlazeBlue, [here's a quick example of event delegation wrt your example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lnjxnkg0/1/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable hoisting + non-scoped variables in `for` loops.
Use `.forEach`:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(del).forEach(function(elem, index) {
    elem.onclick = ...
});
```

Or if you can't, use an immediately-invoked anonymous function:

```
for (var x = 0; x < del.length; x++) {
    (function() {
        var elem = del[x];
        ...
    })();
}
```

---

When you iterate through the loop, there is only ever one `x` variable. It is not scoped to the `for` loop, and changes on each iteration (`x++`). When you trigger a click, the event handler is called, which in turn calls `WORK` with the value of `x` as an argument, which would've already been `del.length` by the time it runs.

Comment: `del` won't be an array...

Comment: thanks both of you for your help, i finally got it to work :3.